# WSO2 IS - OAuth2/OIDC Giving the same token

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have an application which leverages Oauth2 OIDC of IS as KM 5.5. I am facing an issue where reauthentication (/oauth2/authorize) keep giving the same access token and expiry_at.

There are two cases where I observed this issue:
1. Silent refresh with an iframe
2. Logout (/oidc/logout) and Login again (if the previous token hasnt expired)

Am I missing any configuration, or this is actually as expected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> reauthentication (/oauth2/authorize) keep giving the same access token and expiry_at

If you request an access token with the same parameters (same user, same scope, same appliction, ..) you may get back the same token if it's still valid (not like a new request will return you a new token). If you REALLY need a new token, you should revoke the existing one.

> Logout (/oidc/logout) and Login again (if the previous token hasnt expired)

User session and access token are not really bound together. You may want to revoke user's access token on logout

Comment: but then, how to do silent refresh for implicit flow if returned token/expiry is the same as before?

Comment: is this a standard flow or just wso2 works like this? because client library never mentioned about this. As far as I know, the client should be able to renew the token/expiry when they reauthenticate thru iframe before the current token expires (for implicit flow). Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Binbo `client should be able to renew the token/expiry when they reauthenticate thru iframe` that's your assumption, nobody promised something like that (access token and user session are not bount). Using implicit grant comes with some limitations (such as no refresh token). You are arbitrarily binding OAuth access token with user session, so you have to deal with it (such as revoking the token and then requesting a new one by reauthenticating). The default (most used) way is code grant, which comes with a refresh token (used to request a new access token).